# Android bringToFront causes flicker

Tags: android, animation, flicker

I am animating three views that are stacked on top of each other. When I tap one that is not the front view, one or two views will slide up or down to uncover the tapped view, bring the tapped view to front, and then return everything to their original position. Most of these work fine. Only when I bring a view to front that I just animated away I get a noticeable flicker.

I have read at least a hundred posts but none contains the solution.
I am posting this to consolidate every suggested solution in one place and to hopefully find a solution.

I know that the animation does not animate the view itself, but just an image. The view stays at its original position. It is definitely related to that. It only happens when bringing a view to front that just moved.

Moving the view to the animation end position before starting the animation or after the animation is finished does not help one bit.

It also is not related to the `AnimationListener.onAnimationEnd` bug, since I derived my own views and intercept `onAnimationEnd` there.

I am using `Animation.setFillAfter` and `Animation.setFillEnabled` to keep the final image at the animation end location.

I tried using `Animation.setZAdjustment` but that one only works for entire screens, not views within a screen.

From what I have learned I suspect that the problem is `bringToFront()` itself, which does a `removeChild()/addChild()` on the parent view. Maybe the `removeChild` causes the redraw showing the view without the removed child briefly.

**So my questions:** Does anyone see anything I missed that could fix this?
Does *Android* maybe have a command to temporarily stop drawing and resume drawing later. Something like a `setUpdateScreen(false) / setUpdateScreen(true)` pair?
That would allow me to skip the *flicker* stage.

Minimal code to demo the effect follows. Tap white to see red move up and back down behind white without *flicker* (white comes to front but does not move). Then tap red to see red move back up from behind white and the flicker when it is brought to front just before it slides back down over white. Weird thing is that the same thing does not always happen when using blue instead of red.

***MainActivity.java***

```
package com.example.testapp;

import com.example.testapp.ImagePanel.AnimationEndListener;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
  private static final int ANIMATION_TIME = 1000;

  private ImagePanel mRed;
  private ImagePanel mWhite;
  private ImagePanel mBlue;
  private int mFrontPanelId;

  private void animate(final ImagePanel panel, final int yFrom, final int yTo,
      final AnimationEndListener animationListener)
  {
    final TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, yFrom, 0, yTo);
    anim.setDuration(ANIMATION_TIME);
    anim.setFillAfter(true);
    anim.setFillEnabled(true);
    if (animationListener != null)
    {
      panel.setAnimListener(animationListener);
    }
    panel.startAnimation(anim);
  }

  public void onClick(final View v)
  {
    final int panelId = v.getId();
    if (mFrontPanelId == panelId)
    {
      return;
    }
    final ImagePanel panel = (ImagePanel) v;

    final int yTop = mWhite.getTop() - mRed.getBottom();
    final int yBot = mWhite.getBottom() - mBlue.getTop();

    final boolean moveRed = panelId == R.id.red || mFrontPanelId == R.id.red;
    final boolean moveBlue = panelId == R.id.blue || mFrontPanelId == R.id.blue;

    animate(mBlue, 0, moveBlue ? yBot : 0, null);
    animate(mRed, 0, moveRed ? yTop : 0, new AnimationEndListener()
    {
      public void onBegin()
      {
      }

      public void onEnd()
      {
        // make sure middle panel always stays visible
        if (moveRed && moveBlue)
        {
          mWhite.bringToFront();
        }

        panel.bringToFront();

        animate(mBlue, moveBlue ? yBot : 0, 0, null);
        animate(mRed, moveRed ? yTop : 0, 0, new AnimationEndListener()
        {
          public void onBegin()
          {
          }

          public void onEnd()
          {
          }
        });

        mFrontPanelId = panelId;
      }
    });
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mRed = (ImagePanel) findViewById(R.id.red);
    mWhite = (ImagePanel) findViewById(R.id.white);
    mBlue = (ImagePanel) findViewById(R.id.blue);
    mFrontPanelId = R.id.red;
  }
}
```

***ImagePanel.java***

```
package com.example.testapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImagePanel extends ImageView
{
  public interface AnimationEndListener
  {
    public void onBegin();

    public void onEnd();
  }

  private AnimationEndListener mAnim = null;

  public ImagePanel(final Context context)
  {
    super(context);
  }

  public ImagePanel(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs)
  {
    super(context, attrs);
  }

  public ImagePanel(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyle)
  {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onAnimationEnd()
  {
    super.onAnimationEnd();
    clearAnimation();
    if (mAnim != null)
    {
      final AnimationEndListener anim = mAnim;
      mAnim = null;
      anim.onEnd();
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onAnimationStart()
  {
    super.onAnimationStart();
    if (mAnim != null)
    {
      mAnim.onBegin();
    }
  }

  public void setAnimListener(final AnimationEndListener anim)
  {
    mAnim = anim;
  }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <com.example.testapp.ImagePanel
        android:id="@+id/blue"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#000080"
        android:src="@drawable/testpattern"
        android:onClick="onClick" />

    <com.example.testapp.ImagePanel
        android:id="@+id/white"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="#808080"
        android:src="@drawable/testpattern"
        android:onClick="onClick" />

    <com.example.testapp.ImagePanel
        android:id="@+id/red"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="#800000"
        android:src="@drawable/testpattern"
        android:onClick="onClick" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

***testpattern.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >

    <gradient

        android:startColor="#00000000"
        android:endColor="#ffffffff" />

</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need all the images be visible at any time? you can set their visibility as invisible so they will not disturb you. you make them visible again once you need them.

Comment: There are only 3 images in the demo app and parts of each are visible at all times.
Actually the app I am building that has this problem has even more images and i do make the non-visible ones invisible.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `animation.cancel()` in `onAnimationEnd`. I remember a while back I had a similar issue with animation flickering after executing code in `onAnimationEnd`and that did the trick.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that as well. Forgot to mention that one. 
It's definitely the `bringToFront()` that causes the flicker.

Answer (score 0):

I was observing the same problems when calling `bringToFront()` during an animation.

I could solve my problem by using `setChildrenDrawingOrderEnabled(boolean enabled)` and `getChildDrawingOrder(int childCount, int i)` on the `ViewGroup` that contained the children I was animating.

Comment: I tried this. I extended the Root layout and implemented getChildDrawingOrder. But in order for the screen to reflect the new order you still need to call invalidate() from your bringChildToFront - which still causes a flicker to any ongoing animation.

Or did you do this differently ?